ERROR: could not compute MD5 hash: disabled for FIPS (PG::InternalError)
I am trying to deploy OpenProject 14 on Azure but using Azure Postgres Felxible Database server. But I get the below error, looks like our Azure tenant is FIPS complaint and below is the error message it is  throwing. Any thoughts?
 Caused by:
       PG::InternalError: ERROR:  could not compute MD5 hash: disabled for FIPS (PG::InternalError)
       /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:894:in `exec_params'
       /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:894:in `block (2 levels) in exec_no_cache'

We would like to deploy Openproject using Azure Postgres flexible server.

PostgreSQL uses OpenSSL's MD5 implementation, and your OpenSSL was compiled in what's known as "FIPS mode" and refuses to calculate MD5 hashes.
Either use a different OpenSSL (not an option on a hosted database) or don't use MD5 or implement your own version of MD5.

I was recently in contact with Microsoft Azure support. They told us that SCRAM is the new default for logins on Azure PostgreSQL Flexible servers and MD5 is disabled on all newly created servers from versions greater than 13.

yes I can confirm this also (MS support informed me about this). currently looking into options who to move on because a few billion index keys would need to be rehashed. there is pycropto which has an md5 in crypt... but I guess we'll move to sha256 which would be quite some effort :( interestingly this was not communicated upfront

and I can confirm that the change was rolled back now for newly created Postgres Flexible Servers (at least for our cloud rooms).
